# Manually raising exceptions over Python XML-RPC

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-rpc

## *Solution at the bottom of this question!*

In my situation, my client sends data to the server to do CPU-intensive workloads. I would like for my XML-RPC server to be able to raise an exception when there is a problem with the input data.

I have tried a simple `raise Exception('description of the error')` on the server side, but on my client, I get: `xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: "<class 'TypeError'>:exceptions must derive from BaseException">`

On the client side, I would like to be able to do the following:

```py
try:
    proxy.processData(data)
except:
    [... code to handle the exception ...]
```

and on the server side:

```py
def processData(data):
    if 'somethingRequired' not in data:
        raise Exception('Something Required not in data!')
    [... continue processing ...]
```

I think it may also be ideal to have the exception be a custom type on the client side, so that exceptions caused by the XML-RPC module (for example, not being able to connect to the XML-RPC server) don't get interpreted as data input errors.

Thanks!

## Update: Solution

Above my `processData` method, I added the following (a custom exception):

```py
class ProcessingError(Exception):
    pass
```

then, in my client code, I used the following for error handling::

```py
try:
    proxy.processData(data)
except xmlrpc.client.Fault as e:
    print(e.faultString)
```

Note that if you would like to differentiate between custom exceptions and exceptions from the XML-RPC module (like connection errors), you can parse `str(e)` in the `except:` block to check if your exception was in the error or not. I don't have that in my code above.

The `xmlrpc.client.Fault` class has a few attributes that can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xmlrpc/client.py#L233).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May need to raise custom exception in your case, `Exception` is trying to refer to a parent class, which you maybe missing. Something like this:

```
class SomeSortOfException(Exception):
   pass
```

This should be at the top or before the scope of the `processData()` function.

Comment: This helped, thanks! I ended up having to create some exception handling in my client code; I'll update the answer to include that shortly.